# Showing Data Points of the day that has the highest value but hiding the days

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, visualization, recharts

This one is very specific. In this chart that I'm working On the X Axis i show the months only, but the chart has 365 days. The dot appears on the day that has the highest value but the tooltip shows all the accumulated value in that month. For more reference look at this picture, and this is my code.What I have achieved is I now show the dots on the highest value of the month but the other days show, and on the X Axis the months repeat. Look at the picture again see how the dots dont appear on top of the month but sometimes at the middle end or start because there are days there but they are hidden.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { AreaChart, Area, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip } from "recharts";

function generateMockData() {
  const data = [];
  const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

  // Generate data for each month
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    const month = months[i];
    const daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(i + 1); // Get the number of days in the month

    // Generate data for each day
    for (let j = 1; j <= daysInMonth; j++) {
      const day = j;
      const value = getRandomValue(); // Generate a random value for the day

      data.push({ month, day, value });
    }
  }

  return data;
}

function getDaysInMonth(month) {
  // Get the number of days in a month
  const date = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), month, 0);
  return date.getDate();
}

function getRandomValue() {
  // Generate a random value between 100 and 1000
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
}

function CustomTick({ x, y, payload }) {
  const { value } = payload;

  return <text x={x} y={y} dy={16} textAnchor="middle" fill="#666">{value}</text>;
}

function AreaChartExample() {
  const data = generateMockData();

  return (
    <AreaChart width={600} height={400} data={data}>
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="month" tick={CustomTick} />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Area
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="value"
        stroke="#8884d8"
        fill="#8884d8"
        dot={(props) => {
          // Display a dot only for the highest value of each month
          const { cx, cy, stroke, payload } = props;
          const { month, day, value } = payload;
          const highestValueOfMonth = Math.max(...data.filter((d) => d.month === month).map((d) => d.value));

          if (value === highestValueOfMonth) {
            return (
              <svg>
                <circle cx={cx} cy={cy} r={4} fill="#8884d8" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth={2} />
              </svg>
            );
          }

          return null;
        }}
      />
    </AreaChart>
  );
}

export default AreaChartExample;
```